# Google Play developer account - error upon registration

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I've tried to create developer account on Google Play but I encountered on problem on switching from step 2 to step 3.

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/#

I have connected card on google Pay, accept both checkbox and click on button to go to payment and send 25$ but nothing happened.
[image]

In network I see error from google:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 668269003,
        "data": {
            "1": 668269003
        }
    }
}
```

Login and logout & attempt on incognito doesn't work in my case

Comment: have u find solution?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: nope, still facing the same problem...

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I have purchased the "business email also" but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution :
You need to accept terms from "new beta" play console from https://play.google.com/console
Once you've accepted terms you will be automaticaly redirect to signup page, AND magic it works (in my case at least)...
Anyway strang bug for a google product

Answer (score 0):

google recently made some updates.

you need to accept google T&C First. Click on this link to accept and proceed to payment ( https://play.google.com/console/accept-terms )

Good luck.